# How to make a sub string selection and concatenation in excel?

Tags: excel, concatenation, substring

I have an excel file with field1 and field2
I want to take the first letter in field1 and concatenate it to field2 and put the result in field3
Example:
Field1 = "John"
Field2 = "Doe"

I want to set the field three by some equation to be 
Field3 = "JDoe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1 = John

A2 = Doe

A3 = LEFT(A1,1) & A2

Syntax:

- LEFT(*text*, *number of chars from the
  left*)
- With '&' you can concatenate two strings